# how can i create this horizontal recycler view(or view pager) in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-motionlayout

when I scroll screen down the item of recycler view became collapse(when scroll down) and expand(when scroll up)
[this is expand mode of item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/setOz.png)

[and this is collapse mode of item of recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSKuo.png)

my question is how can I implement this view item in my list?
thanks for help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewpager inside CollapsingToolbarLayout if I've got what you really want.

read this article for more info :
https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Comment: thanks but this link just talk about main collapsing toolbar and didn't solve my problem. you can see this horizontal list at the bam application of Bank Melli Iran